# How can I convert my Raspberry Pi into a Wi-Fi network in order to receive a device configuration in a captive portal?

Tags: wifi, boot, access-point, raspi-config, captive-portal

**Initial Situation:** Device: Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W with Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64-bit)

I aim to establish a seamless Raspberry Pi configuration that transitions between two distinct modes:

**Setup Mode:** In this mode, when the Raspberry Pi initially boots up and fails to detect a configuration file, it transforms into a user-friendly Wi-Fi hotspot. This facilitates easy device connection, akin to the method used in hotels or airports for Wi-Fi access. Once connected, a captive portal emerges, allowing for device configuration. After configuration, the device will initiate a reboot.

**Operational Mode:** After configuring the Raspberry Pi in setup mode, it will retain the Wi-Fi network settings from the captive portal configuration. It will automatically connect to a production server and commence its designated tasks.

The key challenge lies in designing a system or script that intelligently detects the presence of a configuration file and, based on that, seamlessly transitions between these two modes. The ultimate goal is to facilitate the transition between serving as a Wi-Fi network and connecting to a Wi-Fi network, contingent on the configuration.

My approach was to define a .service in `/etc/systemd/system/` which executes this .sh

```
if [ -f /etc/gm-setup ]; then
    echo "The configuration file /etc/gm-setup exists."
else
    echo "The configuration file /etc/gm-setup does not exist."

    # Execute the script setup-mode.sh
    if [ -f /etc/setup-mode.sh ]; then
        echo "Executing the script setup-mode.sh."
        # Insert the command here to execute setup-mode.sh
        /path/to/setup-mode.sh
    else
        echo "The script setup-mode.sh was not found."
    fi
fi
```

If the file does not exist, `setup-mode.sh` should be executed accordingly, which will temporarily convert the Pi into a Wi-Fi network.

How can I convert the Raspberry Pi into a Wi-Fi network and how can I convert it back so that I can use the antenna to connect to a network myself?